# Url not supporting to play a video in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, video

I have to play the  video in my `Iphone` application but i am unable to find the below link is of what kind and how to play it? [This video](http://player.vimeo.com/video/71626686). tested in many ways but still not found the best practice.

Comment: When i am playing i am getting a black screen.

Comment: please post some code ? so we can easily finf out problem

Comment: can you post your code? I think problem in your video format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it

MPMoviePlayerController   declared in .h file

```
-(void)playVideo:(id)sender
 {


     NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[newsFeedsMA objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"url"]];
     _player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

     [self.view addSubview:_player.view];

     [_player prepareToPlay];
     _player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
     _player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
     [_player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

 }

 //Notification method:



    - (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
     {

         MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

         if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
         {
             [player.view removeFromSuperview];
         }
     }
```

Comment: might be problem  with url. in my mac url is not running in the browser  but it is running in another mac. i am sure it is not youtube url. what kind of  url it is , do i need to install any additional software in my mac 10.7.5 ? Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: Url type as http://www.abc.com/UserVideo/35ca89da-9b89-4210-9c08-7365258ba560.mp4